# Kwargs isnt passing

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, django-views

I am trying to pass some information to a view in Django in order to filter a list and then pass this back to the user. In order to do so I have the following in my urls.py:

`url(r'^info/user/(?P<user_id>\d+)$', views.UserInfoView, name='active_reservations'),`

and the following view defined:

```
def UserInfoView(request, **kwargs):
    template = "parking/detail_user.html"
    user = User.objects.filter(user=self.kwargs['user_id'])
    context = {"user": user}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

However, each time I try this I get the error: NameError at /info/user/1
global name 'self' is not defined

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the view function. Replace **kwargs with *user_id*

```
def UserInfoView(request, user_id):
    template = "parking/detail_user.html"
    user = User.objects.filter(user=user_id)
    context = {"user": user}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Answer (score 1):

kwargs is not an attribute of self. Your code should be:

`user = User.objects.filter(user=kwargs['user_id'])`